# System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException error C++/CLi with icon file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

Hello so recently on my project I changed the icon of the window form app on the **properties > window Style > Icon** 
Here is the icon I chose:

[image]

,but whenever I launch my app, I get this error:

```sh
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "formApp.MyForm.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "formApp" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.'
```

at this line:

```cpp
this->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^>(resources->GetObject(L"$this.Icon")));
```

`$this.Icon` corresponds to `hello.ico`.

Any idea on how I could fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any resource named `$this.Icon`.

Comment: `hello.ico` != `$this.Icon`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I changed it but it still produces the same thing, and here this.icon points to the correct icon...

Comment: `resource.rc` has it as `IDI_ICON1` but the code tries to load it as `"hello.ico"`.

Comment: @dxiv I don't understand whenever I try to change the logo using properties>window style> icon and then build it, it loads infinitly. I don't understand....

Comment: @dxiv what do you mean?

Comment: @Alex The snapshots alone that you posted do not conclusively verify that you have a resource by the name of `"hello.ico"` compiled into the executable. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @dxiv man seriously? There is a resource folder with `hello.ico` inside it which I posted as a picture and is the one I'm using. I just went inside my window properties and changed the Icon but then I get this error.

Comment: @Alex Yes, seriously. The (managed) resource would be inside the `.resx` file, not a separate `.ico` file. It's hard to guess what went wrong in your case as long as you don't post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my problem by inspiring myself from this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms950960(v=msdn.10)), changing my own code to this:

```cpp
this->Icon = gcnew System::Drawing::Icon("your_ico_fil_path");
```

Comment: FWIW this is more of a different way to do it than a fix per se. The `this->Icon = ...` line in the question should have worked as-is, but something else was wrong, likely with the `.resx` XML resource.

Comment: @dxiv Yes I know, however I think that was a bug, because on the other projects I opened it didn't work. I also added a resource file with the icon but it still throwed this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem on this subject, then I resolved to use this technique, but the problem is that it cannot directly carry the images, which is a pity (also works for icons...). And I realized that in the error he was talking about the "project name" I changed it at the top of MyForm.h and MyForm.cpp to match that of the project name. and after that it worked I don't know if it will work for you but I hope so and I say goodbye. ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but when I tried the method Alex proposed, I couldn't see images in the designer. When Mohamed proposed to change some names, I noticed adding images (and icons) on my similar project worked because of similar names.

So I changed the entry point name to Main (in the compiler properties), and then the FORM name to Main (While my project name is Project1 !), and it works for me, hope it works for you too!